# What is the size of partitions versus subsets?

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

I know this might be a newbie question, but it's confusing to me.

What is a partition, does it only apply to integers? And how does the size of it compare to the size of subsets?

Also, suppose we have a set {A,B,C,D} and a set  {A,B,C,D,E}? How does the number of partitions in each compare? i.e, how does the size of partitions grow as it's members increases?'

For the set {A,B,C,D} I think the partitions are:

```
{ABCD} , {ABC, D}, {AB, CD},
```

etc??

I appreciate any tips or help.

Comment: "Partition" can refer to two things: a partition of a natural number and a partition of a set. For the former see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory) and for the latter see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_numbers .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In combinatorics, the $n$th Bell number, named after Eric Temple Bell, is the number of partitions of a set with $n$ members, or equivalently, the number of equivalence relations on it.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number) has info on the definition of this function, which can be defined recursively as

$$ B_{n+1}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{{n \choose k}B_k} $$

with $B_1 = 1$. It turns out that this number grows very fast; see [OEIS A000110](http://oeis.org/A000110) for the first few Bell numbers. Specifically, there are 15 and 52 partitions of a 4- and 5-element set, respectively.

Also, interestingly, there is a correspondence between integer partitions and set partitions and also between vector partitions and multiset partitions. You can use this fact to list all set partitions for a set of size $m$ by generating the integer partition of $m$ and having a correspondence between the numbers $1\cdots{}m$ and the members of your set. The multiset case is roughly the same but using the vector partition concept instead, where the vector in question is a vector of multiplicity counts (one for each element in the multiset). Knuth is a good reference on this.